# ML compile error in a function

Tags: compilation, smlnj, ml

After hours of fixing the following code I got stuck in the following compile error message and no matter what I try, I cannot fix it.

Error: syntax error: deleting  END RPAREN FUN

the code is:

```
 fun we  (array1 , k, n, fif1) = if Queue.isEmpty fif1 then (array1, ~1 , n ,
   fif1 )
    else (  
     let
        val b = Queue.head(fif1)
        val y = Queue.dequeue(fif1)
        val z = #1 b
        in 
            if ( (Array.sub (array1 , z))  = (What) ) then (array1 , #2 y ,    n    , fif1 ) else 
            (
            if (Array.sub (array1 ,(z+n) ) <> ( Block) ) then (
            ( Queue.enqueue ( fif1 , (z, (#2 b) ))) ; Array.update (array1 , ((z)+n) , Block)) else (); 
            if ( (Array.sub (array1 , (z+1)) ) <> ( Block) ) then (
            Queue.enqueue ( fif1 ,((z+1), ((#2b) + 1)));  Array.update (array1 , (z+1) , Block)) else () ; 
            if (Array.sub (array1 , (z-1 ) ) <> ( Block) ) then (
            Queue.enqueue ( fif1 , (((z-1), ((#2 b)+1) ) )) ; Array.update (array1 , (z-1) , Block)) else () ; 
            if ( (Array.sub (array1 , (z-n ) )) <> (Block) ) then 
            ( Queue.enqueue ( fif1 , ((z-n), ((#2 b)+2 )) );  Array.update (array1 , (z-n) , Block) ) else () ;
            we (array1 , k, n , fif1));
        end ) 

fun tb filename =
let
 val (n, array1) = parse filename
 val c = findt (T, array1, 0) 
 val fif1 = Queue.mkQueue ()
in
  #2 we (array1, 0, n, Queue.enqueue (fif1 , (c,0) ) )
end
```

and the error message is about this part of the code

```
we (array1 , k, n , fif1));
            end ) 

    fun tb filename =
```

any possible help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
            we (array1 , k, n , fif1));
        end )
```

In SML `;` is a statement *separator*, not a statement *terminator*. What this means is: if you have a block containing multiple statements, you put `;`s between the statements, but you do not put a `;` after the last statement in the block. In other words: there should be no `;` after `we (array1 , k, n , fif1))`.

```
#2 we (array1, 0, n, Queue.enqueue (fif1 , (c,0) ) )
```

Here you're calling `#2` with two arguments: the function `we` and the tuple `(array1,...)`. What you meant to do is to call `we` with the tuple as its argument and then call `#2` with the result as its argument. That would be `#2 (we (array1, 0, n, Queue.enqueue (fif1 , (c,0) ) ) )`.

Comment: Thanks alot! I'll try to fix it. if anything else comes up, I'm going to comment here and I'd be grateful if you can check this question a little bit later in case I got some other problems with the code.

Comment: Now the problem that arises is the following: val fif1 = Queue.mkQueue ()
in
  #2 (we (array1, 0, n, Queue.enqueue (fif1 , (c,0) ) ))       stdIn:60.6-60.32 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: unit
  operand:         int * int
  in expression:
    Queue.mkQueue (0,0)
stdIn:61.9-61.57 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: square array * int * int * (int * int) Queue.queue
  operand:         square array * int * int * unit
  in expression:
    bfs1 (array1,0,n,Queue.enqueue (fif1,(,)))